# Evaluate a three parametric integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, special-functions, contour-integration

I would like to get some advices or procedures on how to evaluate this three parametric integral:

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{s^{\alpha}}{(1+s^2)(1+s)^{\beta}}\sin(k\,s)\;ds$$

$$(a\in\mathbb{Z}), \; (\beta\in\mathbb{Z},\; \beta>1), \;(k\in\mathbb{R},\; k\geq0).$$

It looks like that one can have an analytical result, I mean, in terms of the classical known functions.

Comment: If $\alpha \le -1$ the integral does not converge near $x=0$.

Comment: @SpettroDiA $\Re\left(\alpha\right) > -2$.

Comment: what is a "classical known  function"?

Comment: @tired elementary functions or special ones ;-)

Comment: @user115376 *"It looks like that one can have an analytical result..."* Your optimism is admirable, but it's probably misplaced. ;) I've already found a couple of special cases where the integrand reduces to something whose solution requires generalized confluent hypergeometric functions (according to Gradshteyn). The best of hope of finding a closed form in terms of well-known functions is if we can assume one or more of the parameters are integers instead of arbitrary real numbers.

Comment: @DavidH yes sure, sorry, only $k$ is real, $a$ and $b$ are integers.